# JSON output via CGI

Tags: python, command-line-interface, cgi

I'm trying to execute a Python script via CGI. There is no problem with the execution of the script. It's the output or display where I am not getting the desired format. I'm running this CGI script with Apache2.

`/usr/lib/cgi-bin/info.cgi`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "content-type: text/html\n\n";
import json
from napalm import get_network_driver
driver = get_network_driver('ios')
hub2 = driver('10.0.0.120', 'admin', 'admin')
hub2.open()

ios_output = hub2.get_facts();
print json.dumps(ios_output, indent=5)
hub2.close()
```

Output looks like this:

```
{ "os_version": "Linux Software (ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 15.5(3)S3,  SOFTWARE", "uptime": 10080, "interface_list": [ "Ethernet0/0", "Ethernet0/1", "Ethernet0/2", "Ethernet0/3" ], "vendor": "Cisco", "serial_number": "67109072", "model": "Unknown", "hostname": "R13", "fqdn": "R13.lab1.com" }
```

But the desired output after running this script via CLI should look like this:

```
"os_version": "Linux Software (ADVENTERPRISEK9-M), Version 15.5(3)S3, 
 SOFTWARE", 
 "uptime": 10920, 
 "interface_list": [
      "Ethernet0/0", 
      "Ethernet0/1", 
      "Ethernet0/2", 
      "Ethernet0/3"
 ], 
 "vendor": "Cisco", 
 "serial_number": "67109072", 
 "model": "Unknown", 
 "hostname": "R13", 
 "fqdn": "R13.lab1.com"
```

Any suggestions how to get the desired output while executing `info.cgi`?

Answer (score 0):

Fix

Changed the content type "/Json"